# Is it correct to use the phrase"be with no access to X"?

Tags: verbs, collocations

Is it correct to say the below?

> She was hungry for knowledge but **with** no access to information.

Or does it require using the verb, namely:

> She was hungry for knowledge but **had** no access to information.

It seems to me that the correct phrase is "have no access to", but I have found a few instances of sentences like "Mothers in developing countries are at present faced with a pandemic **with no access to** basic health care."

Answer (score 2):

It's fine, although not always very elegant, and you can certainly use various alternatives instead.

Examples with copula (*to be with no access*):

- "The vulnerable groups are with no access to essential health services." [World Federation of Public Health Associations press release](https://www.wfpha.org/physicians-under-bombardment-in-solidarity-with-frontline-health-heroes-and-heroines/), 2023
- "Society is becoming ever more dependent on computerised technologies, but thousands of people are still with no access to this vital resource and as a consequence living in social and digital exclusion here in London." [South West News Services](https://stories.swns.com/news/laptop-recycling-programme-will-benefit-homeless-and-vulnerable-people-across-london-70007/), 2015
- "According to AI (Amnesty International), these children end up being displaced and are with no access to education." [The Cable](https://www.thecable.ng/amnesty-how-children-who-escaped-boko-haram-captivity-are-tortured-in-detention), Nigeria, 2020
- "they are with no access to legal water and electricity supply." [Heliyon](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9898597/), 2023
- "According to United Nations Children's Fund, 640 million children are without adequate shelter (1 in 3), 270 million are with no access to health services (1 in 7) and 15 million children are orphaned due to HIV/AIDS" [Go To Nations website](https://gotonations.org/our-mission)

It's also possible to use with other copular verbs such as *to remain with no access*:

- "In addition, some social groups remain with no access to these basic rights", [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/roomfordebate/2013/06/19/will-the-protests-in-brazil-lead-to-change/the-protestors-in-brazil-have-a-unifying-goal-to-be-heard), 2013
- "More than 625,000 students remain with no access to education or a safe place in Gaza Strip", [Save the Children](https://twitter.com/scegypt/status/1750128022244466824), Twitter
- "Worldwide about 1.7 billion people remain with no access to banking facilities", [Front Psychiatry](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32581882/), 2020

Although *to be* and similar verbs are commonly followed by a noun phrase or adjective, they can also be followed by a prepositional phrase: "They are in the shed", "The apples are with the other fruits", etc.

Comment: @Ania Despite the examples here, it's unusual to use "[to be] *with* [property or state]" as in this question, aside from the idiom "to be with child." It's far more common to get another verb involved as in the later examples, like "... are left with no ___" or "are faced with ___" or similar.